# SvelteKit doesn't load landing page (but all other pages...?)

Tags: node.js, debugging, production, vite, sveltekit

I have a weird issue with my SvelteKit Website: **The landing page ('/') is not working, but all other pages are.**

This is **only happening when I build and run in production**, otherwise all pages load normally:

- `vite dev`: Everything works normally
- `vite preview`: Everything works normally
- `vite build && node build/`: Landing does not load, all other pages do.

See for yourself:

- go to https://wildwaid.com/datenschutz: Page works!
- go to https://wildwaid.com/: Page doesn't work.

I tried working out with curl what the problem could be, but if you curl the site, everything seems to work....
It also is not a problem with the landing page itself, since even if I just put "Test" in the file, it still doesn't load.

The issue accured first, when I updated my dependencies and `svelte-kit build` became `vite build`.

I'd be happy for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem sovled itself:
It seems this was an effect of SvelteKit in combination with vite v2.9.10.
Once I updated vite to v3.0.0, the problem disappeared and everything worked again.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have the exact same issue. Vite is a "peer dependant", right? How do you update that  ?

Comment: @JesperOrdrup You can just add it to your package.json :)